# Copying data pointed at by pointer into another pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, copy

I've looked at some similar questions but no solutions is working for my case.

I've got a class that has an update function that runs continously. This function has an `unsigned short*` argument that contains the 2D data of an image, which is different every time update is called. At the beggining of execution I want to keep the first frame data in a separate `unsigned short*`, and this data must be alive through all the execution.

//setup runs once at the beginning of execution

```
void Process::setup() 
{
    ...
    _firstFrame = new unsigned short; //_firstFrame is an unsigned short* private variable from the class

    return;
}

void Process::update(unsigned short* frame)
{   
    //-- Performing an initial calculation before any further processing
    if (!_condition)
    {
        //some processing that changes condition to true when criteria is met
        if (condition)
            memcpy(_firstFrame, frame, sizeof(640*480*sizeof(unsigned short)));
                    //each frame has 640*480 dimensions and each element is an unsigned short

        return;
    }

    //further processing using frame
}
```

Now, _firstFrame is supposed to always keep data from that frame that originated after condition was met, but _firstFrame only contains zeros.
Any help?

Comment: You're only allocating space for one unsigned short. Presumably you want an array.

Comment: Do you want to copy *to* or *from* `_firstFrame`? Remember that the destination argument of `memcpy` comes first.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question because this code was copy pasted after I switched them to check if I was passing the arguments wrong, generating a segmentation fault obviously.

Comment: Problem solved. Had to change _firstFrame = new unsigned short; to _firstFrame = new unsigned short[480*640]; and memcpy(_firstFrame, frame, sizeof(640*480*sizeof(unsigned short))); to memcpy(_firstFrame, frame, 640*480*sizeof(unsigned short));

Answer (score 2):

You need an array, but you *always* need it so it isn't necessary to allocate it dynamically.

You also need to initialise it, exactly once, so you need some way to track that. Currently you (try to) allocate your first frame when you don't know what should go in it.

```
class Process {
  bool got_first;
  unsigned short first_frame[640*480];

public:
  Process() : got_first(false) {}

  void update(unsigned short *frame) {
    if (!got_first) {
      memcpy(first_frame, frame, sizeof(first_frame));
      got_first = true;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried it but it doens't work. I used    for (int n =  0; n < 640*480; n++)
    cout << _firstFrame[n] << endl; To check if _firstFrame values made sense but they dont. It is mostly zeros with some occasional positive values. Frame has virtually no zeros because of the nature of the data, so somethng is going wrong when I try to copy it

Comment: There is nothing called `firstFrame` in my code. Did your code fail to compile? Did it fail at runtime? How? what _was_ your code anyway?

Comment: i changed the declaration from unsigned short* _firstFrame to unsigned short _firstFrame[640*480] and then removed the "new" allocation from setup.. I guess it is essencially the same thing

Comment: You need to show minimal, self-contained code that has a problem, and then say what the actual problem is. You're not using my code above, or your code from the question, and I still don't know which bit doesn't work.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that the project is very big and has a complex architecture, so It is a challenge to put all the code that here. Your code is just the same as the one I have in the OP, but instead of declaring firstframe as an unsigned short* and then allocating space with new, you declare an array like unsigned short firstFrame[480*640]. It is exactly the same thing, and I tried it your way and firstFrame is mostly filled with zeros which indicates me that the frame is not being correctly copied.

Comment: You need to reduce and simplify your code to something you _can_ post. Doing so often reveals the problem anyway, and makes your code more testable.